# How to inherit base.xml file in odoo 9

Tags: xml, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want to inherit and modify a template   t-name = "ListView.row" in base.xml. file

I want to add the another 'td' column and 'th' column .
 at line no 463 in base. xml .

using my custom module.
Thanks,
Anand.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <tr t-extend="ListView.row">
        <t t-jquery="t td t" t-operation="after">
        <!-- Add your code here and you can update the xpath as you needed on t-jquery attribute -->
    </tr>
```

Comment: Ok, but where to put it? As I can see, an addon can not contain a `<templates>` tag.